# How do I delete Azure Databricks resource group?

Tags: azure, databricks

I tried following the Quickstart: Run a Spark job on Azure Databricks using the Azure portal as described at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-portal

But when I later try to delete resource group for that **databricks** resource I got the following two errors:

> Delete resource group databricks-rg-mydatabricksws-5mlo3dio7wef2
>   failed The resource group databricks-rg-mydatabricksws-5mlo3dio7wef2
>   is locked and can't be deleted. Click here to manage locks for this
>   resource group.
>
> UnauthorizedApplicationId "The management lock ... is owned by system
>   application"

See: https://aka.ms/arm-lock

> Lock Deletion Failure The lock named mydatabricksws was unable to be
>   deleted for the following reasons: {"errorThrown":"Unavailable in
>   batch","jqXHR":{"responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"UnauthorizedApplicationId","message":"The
>   management lock 'mydatabricksws' is owned by system application(s)
>   'd9327919-6775-4843-9037-3fb0fb0473cb'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem before. I get the answer from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/account#delete-an-azure-databricks-service).

> - Log into your Azure Databricks workspace as the account owner (the user who created the service), and click the user profile Account  [image]icon at the top right.

[image]

> - Select Manage Account.

[image]

> - In the Azure Databricks service, click Azure Delete [image] and then OK.

You also could get the Azure Databricks code demo from this [document](https://github.com/TomSunGit/DatabricksDemo/blob/master/README.md).